# How can I view my browsing history in Internet Explorer 9 (Beta)?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Is it possible to view IE9's browsing history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the Favorites button - it opens a popup menu where you should see a tab named "History".

[image]

Comment: ***shell:history*** _command_ ? How **export history** to txt, xml, csv ?

Comment: This works for both Internet Explorer 9 and 10